# Include relation models not working

Tags: loopbackjs

i have a Contrato model that has many Item model and in my Item model it has a Produto model.

So, basic, my Item belongs to one Produto and my Item belongs to one Contrato, but a Contrato can have a lot of Items. The problem is that i want to get all the Contratos with the Items and on each Item the Produto.

After reading the documentation, it seens the case:

```
/customers?filter[include][reviews]=author
```

But the result is that the Contratos has the items but each item only has the id of the Produto and not the Produto object itself.. What i am doing wrong?

Here is the response that i am receiving:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "codigoTemplate": null,
        "status": "aguardando",
        "prazoFinalizacao": "2017-11-17T02:00:00.000Z",
        "dataInicio": "2017-10-01T23:47:10.000Z",
        "dataFinalizacao": null,
        "emailComissao": "email@hotmail.com",
        "dono": null,
        "usuario": 2,
        "itens": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "quantidade": 5,
                "contrato": 1,
                "produto": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "quantidade": 3,
                "contrato": 1,
                "produto": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My Contrato realtions:

```
"relations": {
    "formandos": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "formando",
      "foreignKey": "contrato"
    },
    "itens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "item",
      "foreignKey": "contrato"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "usuario",
      "foreignKey": "usuario"
    }
  }
```

My Item relations:

```
"relations": {
    "itemFormando": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "itemFormando",
      "foreignKey": "item"
    },
    "produto":{
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "produto",
      "foreignKey": "produto"
    }
  }
```

And my Produto relations:

```
"relations": {
    "item": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "item",
      "foreignKey": "produto"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry cannot put a comment,

As in your **Contrato Model** hasMany Itens and in your **Item** model you didn't mention that your item belongsTo **Contrato** which is fine,

So try to remove the relation in **produto** and keep the relation in **Item** model because one relation is sufficient.

After that call it in include with the scope :
in your find function :

```
   include: {
            relation: 'produto',
            scope: {
              fields: ['Fields that you want to call'],
            },
          },
```

Hope it helps